# Subversion: Can trunk be reset to previous revision after branching/tagging?

Tags: svn, branch, revert

I have many projects depending on each other in trunk. I made several commits
which led to dependency problems.
I tagged /trunk to /tags/trunk-experimental
and now want to "revert" the last N changes (which led to problems), so 
that my /trunk is good again.

Can this be done in a straightforward way?

*I tried to just check out from a certain revision, but this
is bad, because an update changes everything back to latest revision
(which contains dependency problems)*

Here's a timeline to understand my question better:

- revision 1000 (good)
- made several changes which lead to dependency problems,
  several commits, now at revision 1050 (bad)
- copied /trunk to /tags/trunk-experimental (revision 1051)
- don't know what to do with trunk to "revert" it back to revision 1000

Answer (score 19):

Just do a reverse merge:

```
svn merge -r1051:1000 .
```

and commit as usual.

Comment: I have a nervous habit of using the "--dry-run" option to "svn merge" before doing it for real...just for a quick sanity check on the scope of the operation.  But then, I'm no Jon Skeet!

Comment: @ivan_ivanovich_ivonoff you should mark this as your answer then